# How to authenticated in subdomain app from parent domain app in django and reactjs

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, typescript

I have a parent domain, example.com, and a subdomain, app.example.com. If a user is already authenticated in the parent domain app, when they are redirected to the subdomain app, they should also be authenticated there. I am using ReactJS for the frontend and Django for the backend. For authentication in Django, I am using the third-party library drf-social-oauth2.

I am new to this concepts.

Thank you :)